# Проблема при создании event'а

Tags: mysql

Вот код:

```
create event 'video_status' 
  on schedule
    every 1 minute
  do
    update videos_video set status='normal'
      where status='new', unix_timestamp(date) >= unix_timestamp(now()) - 60;
```

Должен проверять статус записи в базе и менять его на другой, значения времени взяты минимальные, для отладки. Структура таблицы(приведены только необходимые столбцы):

```
describe videos_video;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date       | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status     | varchar(10)      | NO   |     | normal  |                |
| errors     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Вопрос теряет свою актуальность, т.к. на сервере установлен mysql 5.0. Однако все же хочется разобраться, ведь тестил я на локальном mysql, с версией 5.1!

Comment: Решил задачу через крон, если кому-то интересно - выложу код.

Answer (score 1):

А если обратные кавычки проставить, особенно вокруг date? И, кстати, зачем нужен `unix_timestamp(now())`? Не проще ли записать `unix_timestamp()`?

Comment: Кавычки ставил, результата нет.
unix_timestamp(now()) нужен для подсчета времени. В идеале событие должно менять статус записи по истечении определенного времени(в данном примере - минута). Да и не во времени ошибка - пробовал без этого параметра - все равно ругается :(